# checking if point is in polygon giving null values

Tags: mysql, spatial

there are many post relating to this matter but most are old and there seem to be many different way of doing it.

I am trying to see if point exists inside a polygon however it is giving null value even though it is point on polygon.

here is my code.

```
select ST_contains(ST_geomfromtext('
      Polygon((127.090656 37.517137, 
      127.092416 37.512525,
      127.098445 37.513836,
      127.095227 37.518346))'), Point(127.090656, 37.517137));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mysql you need to close the polygon therefore I must add first point at the end of polygon again.

```
select ST_contains(ST_geomfromtext('
      Polygon((**127.090656 37.517137**, 
      127.092416 37.512525,
      127.098445 37.513836,
      127.095227 37.518346,
      **127.090656 37.517137**))'), Point(127.090656, 37.517137));
```

which now fixes my problem

and for cleaniness

I can set polygon as

```
SET @location_1 = ST_geomfromtext('
      Polygon((**127.090656 37.517137**, 
      127.092416 37.512525,
      127.098445 37.513836,
      127.095227 37.518346,
      **127.090656 37.517137**))');

select ST_contains( @location_1, Point(127.090656, 37.517137));
```

which to me is much cleaner. But maybe it require more memory for @location_1 in db (I'm not sure)?